# Chaining two Observables to return another

Tags: java, reactive-programming, retrofit, rx-java

I have two observables named A<'ModelA'> and B<'ModelB'>. Each of them performs a request to a different REST service, so they extend a different model like expressed above. The request performed by any of them may fail. Now, I need to be able to chain both of them and return a ModelC object. So, the pseudo-coded stream would be something like this:

A<'ModelA'> performs the request, if it fails does something, if not then passes its result (responseModelA) to B<'ModelB'> so it can perform another REST request which involves using part of responseModelA. If B fails something happens, if not then combines its response (responseModelB) together with responseModelA (manually, setting the POJO fields) to create ModelC which is what the subscriber should recieve as a parameter on it's *call()* method.

Is this remotely possible to code using rxJava? I'm quite stucked into this so I'm open to any sugestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Try looking up observer pattern. Looks like it might be what you are looking for. Or if you want a minimum working setup, have B be a property in A. On method call to process A, make a call to process B when it is done, and return C. This tightly couples your code and is not recommended. I bring it up for sake of having something working to start with

Comment: What do you mean by "pass its results to B<'ModelB'>". Is B<'ModelB'> a Subject (i.e an IObservable + IObserver) ?

Comment: @nikoniko By "pass" I mean that the response of the first request (A) should be available to B. B is not a subject, is another observable. I'm using Retrofit for the requests and taking advantage of its support for RxJava.

Comment: @coffeeaddict I'll check that pattern. I agree the property thing might work, but like you said it will tightly couple everything up and that goes a little against what rx is about ;-)

Comment: Assume A generates a1, a2, ... and calling REST for them results in A1, A2, ... respectively. Also assume that B generates b1, b2, and so on. What you want to do is to call REST using b1 and A1 to generate C1, b2 and A2 to generate C2, and so on. Is that correct ?

Comment: Let me clarify this. Retrofit wraps up the response into an observable. For example: A<modelA> observable = retrofitService.requestA(someParam). The same applies for B, but the parameter comes from modelA which gets filled on the first request. C is just a POJO. I'm on a cellphone right now, but I'll update the question with some code ASAP to explain it better. Still, your are extremely close to what I want, with code I'll make it clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This assumes you have created a REST request interface that returns Observables similar to the following (using Retrofit this is quite easy):

```java
interface RestApi {
    Observable<ModelA> getModelA();
    Observable<ModelB> getModelB(int modelBId);
}

class ModelA {
    int modelBId;
    Object fieldA;
}

class ModelB {
    Object fieldB;
}

class ModelC {
    Object fieldFromA;
    Object fieldFromB;

    public ModelC(Object fieldFromA, Object fieldFromB) {
        this.fieldFromA = fieldFromA;
        this.fieldFromB = fieldFromB;
    }
}
```

To make the ModelB request depend on the result of the ModelA request, you can use .flatMap to transform the results of one Observable into another Observable.

Then, to create ModelC, use .map to pick the desired fields from ModelA and ModelB and return the result.

```java
RestApi restApi;

Observable<ModelC> observeModelC() {
    return restApi
            .getModelA()
            .flatMap(new Func1<ModelA, Observable<ModelC>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<ModelC> call(final ModelA modelA) {
                    // Use the modelBId from modelA to get ModelB.
                    return restApi
                            .getModelB(modelA.modelBId)
                            // Combine A & B to create C
                            .map(new Func1<ModelB, ModelC>() {
                                @Override
                                public ModelC call(ModelB modelB) {
                                    return new ModelC(modelA.fieldA, modelB.fieldB);
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
}
```

Your subscriber would look like this:

```java
observeModelC()
        .subscribe(new Observer<ModelC>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                // All done.
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                // All errors from any API request will end up here.
                // For Retrofit, cast e to RetrofitError for
                // detailed error info.
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ModelC modelC) {
                // Yeah! - Use modelC.
            }
        });
```

Comment: This can be simplified to directly creating `ModelC` from A + B and not via intermediate `CombinedModelAB`.

Comment: @MaciejGórski Done - Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Sequential composition is achieved in Rx.NET by `SelectMany` (I think it's `FlatMap` in Rx.Java?).  Rx.NET also applies fail-fast semantics, thus `SelectMany` may be all that you need.

(C#)

```
IObservable<ModelC> query = A().FlatMap(B, (a, b) => C(a, b));

query.Subscribe(success => DoSomethingSuccessful(), error => DoSomethingElse(error));
```

where `A` and `B` are functions that return observables, and `C` is a function that returns ModelC.

However, if you want to do something specific when either A or B fails, then a quick solution in Rx.NET is to use the `Do` operator.

```
IObservable<ModelC> query = A().Do(_ => {}, AFailed)
                               .FlatMap(B.Do(_ => {}, BFailed), (a, b) => C(a, b));

query.Subscribe(success => DoSomethingSuccessful(), UltimateFailure);
```

where `AFailed` and `BFailed` are void-returning methods that accept a single `Exception` parameter.

Sorry I don't know Java, but maybe this will lead you to the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this one! Your answer was right, however due to the programming language had to mark kjones answer as the correct one. Thanks again.